# Failed to add the foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to create two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Submissions
(
  quiz_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED,
  quiz_duration TIME,
  student_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED,
  attempt_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY (quiz_ID, student_ID)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
  student_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED,
  student_name VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_ID) REFERENCES Submissions(student_ID)
);
```

However, when I try to create the second table, it gives me an error

> ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'students_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'Submissions'

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key must reference a primary key. You have defined the primary key of SUBMISSIONS as a compound key of `(quiz_ID, student_ID)`. Consequently this does not match the foreign key reference of STUDENTS, where you attempt to reference a single column `Submissions(student_ID)`. That's why you get the error.

But let's drill down into this. You tagged your question `[database-design]`, and that was a good call because this issue arises from your data model.

A student can (presumably) participate in more than one quiz and therefore have more than one submission. This indicates that your data model is wrong. Whenever we have a 1:M relationship the 1 end (in this case STUDENTS) is referenced by a foreign key on the M end (i.e. SUBMISSIONS).

It also seems likely that your data model is missing a table for QUIZZES, and SUBMISSIONS should in fact be an intersection table.

Given all this, your tables should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Quizzes
(
  quiz_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED,
  quiz_duration TIME
  PRIMARY KEY (quiz_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Students
(
  student_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED,
  student_name VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Submissions
(
  quiz_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED,
  student_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED,
  attempt_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY (quiz_ID, student_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (quiz_ID) REFERENCES Quizzes(quiz_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_ID) REFERENCES Students(student_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the foreign keys in the wrong order.  The `submissions` should have the foreign key constraint.  So:

```
CREATE TABLE Submissions (
    quiz_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED,
    quiz_duration TIME,
    student_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED,
    attempt_date date,
    PRIMARY KEY (quiz_ID, student_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_subsmissions_student_id FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id)
);
```

Of course, the `Students` table needs to be created, before the foreign key is defined.

Comment: Thank you, but database is meant to keep records of submissions not students. If a student does not submit a quiz, they shouldn’t be included in the database.

Comment: @user14545805 . . . First, students can exist without submissions -- otherwise it is hard to see how the first submission is created.  More relevantly, though, that condition doesn't have anything to do with the foreign key relationship.